# nothing is happening when clicking onchange

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

When I select a data in Q1, E2, and T3, the data in A4 and Ave does not change. I have onchange attribute in all input and select tag.

```js
function calc(Q1id, E2id, T3id, distroid, A4id, Aveid, ) {
  var Q1 = parseInt(document.getElementById(Q1id).value);
  var E2 = parseInt(document.getElementById(E2id).value);
  var T3 = parseInt(document.getElementById(T3id).value);
  var distro = parseInt(document.getElementById(distroid).value);

  var result = parseFloat(distro) / 100;

  var ratingAve = document.getElementById(A4id).value = parseFloat(Math.round(Q1 + E2 + T3) / 3).toFixed(2);

  document.getElementById(Aveid).value = parseFloat(ratingAve * result).toFixed(2);

}
```

```html
<form action="{{route('notes.update',$note->id)}}" method="POST">
  {{csrf_field()}} {{method_field('PUT')}}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="body">
     Q1
    </label>
    <select name="Q1" id="Q1" onchange="calc('Q1','E2','T3','distro','A4','Ave')" value="{{$note->Q1}}>
               <option value=" 0 ">0</option>
               <option value="1 ">1</option> 
               <option value="2 ">2</option>  
               <option value="3 ">3</option>  
               <option value="4 ">4</option>  
               <option value="5 ">5</option>   
          </select>
                <label for="body ">
     E2
    </label>
    <select name="E2 " id="E2 " onchange="calc( 'Q1', 'E2', 'T3', 'distro', 'A4', 'Ave') " value="{{$note->E2}}>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <label for="body">
     T3
    </label>
    <select name="T3" id="T3" onchange="calc('Q1','E2','T3','distro','A4','Ave')" value="{{$note->T3}}>
               <option value=" 0 ">0</option>
               <option value="1 ">1</option> 
               <option value="2 ">2</option>  
               <option value="3 ">3</option>  
               <option value="4 ">4</option>  
               <option value="5 ">5</option>   
          </select>
   </div>
         <div class="form-group ">
          <label for="body ">
              A4
                </label>
             <input class="form-control " type="text " name="A4 " placeholder="A4 " id="A4 " readonly onchange="calc( 'Q1', 'E2', 'T3', 'distro', 'A4', 'Ave') " value="{{$note->A4}}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="body">
              Ave
                 </label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Ave" placeholder="Average" id="Ave" readonly onchange="calc('Q1','E2','T3','distro','A4','Ave')" value="{{$note->Ave}}">
  </div>
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Done">
</form>
```

I want to change the value in A4 and Ave automatically when I change the value in Q1, E2, T3.

Comment: Use a validator. It will spot errors like the quotes you left off.

Comment: `<label for="body">` — you don't have any elements with `id="body"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

… and you don't have an element with the id `distro` (which is the value of you pass to the `distroid` variable) … or even an element with an id sufficiently like that to look like typo.

You can't read values from elements that don't exist.

Comment: Deleted my answer, you were right. Missed it with the bad formatting/indenting of the question, cheers for pointing it out.